# SQL Server select and combine values across rows with equal columns

Tags: sql-server, select, distinct, concatenation

There are a couple questions I have found that touch a little on this but nothing that fits all my needs in this case. Unfortunately, I am not good enough at SQL yet to put them all together.

Basically I am selecting several rows from a table and I want to only select rows with distinct values for one column but to combine values from all the rows that are hidden from a different column and show that sum in the row that does show.

Also, I would like to select the distinct values from just 1 column.

Here is an example:

```
ID  #_of_Items  Place   Description
=======================
1        2       CA     towels
2        4       NY     shirts
3        1       MA     hats
4        3       CA     shorts
4        2       CA     pins
4        4       NY     socks
```

and I want to select:

```
Place    #_of_Items
=======================
CA        7
NY        8
MA        1
```

only need the two columns - basically, the place is unique, but it takes the sum of all the #_of_items from the hidden rows and adds them to the one row for each state it shows.

Then, if possible, I would also like to select a combination of all the distinct entries in the description column, so:

```
"towels, shirts, hats, shorts, pins, socks"
```

I hope that makes sense.

Thank you so much in advance everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can create user defined functions in your database (replace  with whatever your table name is):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.JoinItems(@place nvarchar(10))
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @list NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @list = CASE WHEN @list IS NULL THEN N'' ELSE @list + N', ' END + description
      FROM <table>
     WHERE place = @place
    RETURN @list
END
GO
```

Which you can then use in your query to return the item count along with the list of items specific to that place (again, replacing  with your table name):

```
SELECT place,
       [#_of_Items] = SUM([#_of_Items]),
       Items = dbo.JoinItems(place)
  FROM <table>
 GROUP BY place
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL 2005+:

```
SELECT ID, Place, Description
      SUM(#_of_Items) OVER(PARTITION BY Place) AS #_of_Items
FROM Your_Table
```

Comment: thank you for your response! I will give it a shot along with the one above it.